# Optimizing CPU load and time in a C++ for loop

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have a C++ function which is called event based on node value change. This function involves a `for` loop which reads around 5000 nodes for the first time and perform some calculation on them. During a read attempt, each node is assigned a node ID by comparing their subscription ID (unique for each node). During the next event this function is called again with nodes whose values are changed. Now this same process is performed, assigning node IDs (using subscription ID) in a `for` loop reading those 5000 stored nodes again.

The question is, is there a better way to link these nodes IDs in the first event run so that next time this event occurs, all the nodes whose value changes do not need to be checked for their node IDs? The subscription ID is a unique number here. At present this function is event based and called very frequently, so comparing 5000 nodes every second causes its CPU load to be always up.

The code:

```
void SubscriptionEvent::handleEvent(EventSource *source, EventArguments *args)
{
     SubscriptionEventArgs* subsArgs = static_cast<SubscriptionEventArgs*>(args);
     vector<string> m_devicesReset;
     if (subsArgs->eventType == SubscriptionEventArgs::VALUECHANGE)
     {
        AgrClient *client = static_cast<AgrClient *>(source);
        OpcUa_UInt32 i = 0;

        bool valueChange =  false;
        if(m_firstEvent == true)
        {
           for (i = 0; i < subsArgs->dataNotifications->length(); i++)
           {
              if (OpcUa_IsGood((*subsArgs->dataNotifications)[i].Value.StatusCode))
              {
                  UaNodeId nodeId;
                  UaStatus status = client->getNodeIdForSubscriptionId((*subsArgs->dataNotifications)[i].ClientHandle, nodeId);  //improve
              }            
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

}

The below input argument

```
(*subsArgs->dataNotifications)[i].ClientHandle
```

is the subscription ID I provide every time to get the ***nodeId***. This last line is the code is to be improved, because the function  `getNodeIdForSubscriptionId()` runs through a for loop to search for the `nodeId` for the provided subscription ID.

Comment: _"...is there a better way..."_ show your code; we shouldn't need to 2nd guess what you wrote. And for all performance type questions you need to profile and measure.

Comment: A better way than what? Show at least the relevant parts of your code instead of discribing them.

Comment: Your last edit adds some clarification (but just a bit). So you probably should have a look into [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: if I got you correctly, you basically want to memoize getNodeIdForSubscriptionId, right ? just store the result into an (unordered)map and remember to remove it/mark it dirty whenever you realize the subscritionid->nodeid association *may* have changed ...